# Uninstalling every program from ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, package-management, uninstall

I installed Arch and was using it for a while, but I want to go back to a completely clean system. Is there a way to uninstall everything that is installed without reinstalling the whole system?

Comment: The original installation installed packages, so maybe clarify what you mean by "uninstall everything that was installed"

Comment: 1) Are you also concerned with data that you (or other users) added to your home directory/other places? (I.e. do you need to clean that up?) 2) Uninstalling is possible, but there is no "predefined" list of installed packages (except for the really basic `base` + `linux` + `linux-firmware`, if your installation is a recent one), so you need to define what you consider a "clean system" - does it also include a desktop environment? Did you install `mdamd`, `lvm`, packages related to your hardware, ... as part of the clean system? In short, it often takes less time to just restart from scratch.